# Are there any side effects of having unix line endings when working on Windows machine?

Tags: node.js, git, newline, tortoisegit, core.autocrlf

I am working on Windows 7 and have a node.js project which is under git. I set up my TortoiseGit to `autocrlf: false` and `safecrlf: false`. Then changed all project files' line endings to LF. The project starts and operates normally and I see no reason to go back to CRLF.

Should I expect any side effects after doing this?

Comment: It doesn't count as a proper answer, but no, you shouldn't expect much of a problem. The only program that was a pain in the neck is `notepad.exe` — it shows files with Unix line separators as one enormous line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no problem at all using *nix end of line sequences on Windows (`LF` instead of `CRLF`).  In fact, my personal recommendation would be to ensure your Windows editor (if you're developing node.js on Windows) to use `LF`.

Just as an example, I use [Visual Studio Code](http://code.visualstudio.com) for my editor developing node.js, and I have specified the following in my user settings to use `LF` instead of `CRLF`: `"files.eol": "\n"`.  Now I no longer need to worry about that.

`CRLF` line endings cause breaking issues in a node.js application that is run on Linux, and [it isn't the most straightforward thing to troubleshoot if you don't know what to look for](http://tstringer.github.io/npmjs/javascript/nodejs/2016/02/26/npm-global-packages.html).

**TL;DR** Use `LF` while developing node.js applications on Windows if you really care about cross-platform (which you should care).

**Note**: just because git changes your line endings doesn't mean that is the solution.  Even if you are ok with your version control changing your source code (which I don't recommend), if you do an `npm publish` it'll be using your source files locally and you could sneak `CRLF`s into the npm registry.

Answer (score 3):

If all tools/editors/IDEs are LF compatible, then there is no problem.

Otherwiese you might get errors or mixed line endings on saving.

In order to make sure no conversion is happening for other users who clone your repository you can put a `.gitattributes` file into the root folder containing: `* -crlf` which disables all crlf conversions.